# Why does MonoTouch UIPickerViewModel have GetTitle?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I see that UIPickerViewModel has a GetTitle method, but I don't understand when it is used or if it is there in error as the GetTitle method that is used on UIPickerViewDelegate is the one that provides the strings to the UIPicker.

As always, I figure maybe I'm missing something. Is there a purpose for the GetTitle on the UIPickerviewModel? I didn't see such a method in the Apple Documentation for the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIPickerViewModel is a blended source (ie; it implements the delegate and the datasource).  If you use the delegate and datasource, you should not use the model.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. So I really should only be using the UIPickerViewModel then. When would you not only use it? i.e. use separate classes.